# NHibernate Linq - how to select WHERE IN

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Given the following domain model:

```
Dog { Id, Name, Color }

Color { Id, Name }
```

How do I get the Colors for which there are dogs with NHibernate.Linq. In SQL I would

```sql
SELECT Color.Id, Color.Name FROM Color 
    WHERE Id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Dog.ColorId FROM Dog);
```

Comment: Try this: Color
.where(c=>
Dogs
.select(d=>d.ColorId)
.Contains(c.ColorId)
)

Comment: Okay - so the reason I had problems quering my object graph, was that I wasn't really supposed to - so even though [Lukazoid's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966207/nhibernate-linq-how-to-select-where-in/7966556#7966556) is indeed valid, I ended up using `CreateSQLQuery` and afterwards a result transformer (`SetResultTransofrmer`) to mock the data down the structure.

Comment: from d in db.Dogs select d.Color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work:

```
Colors.Where(c => Dogs.Any(d => d.Color.Equals(c)))
```

However if you are matching purely on the color identifier, try this instead:

```
Colors.Where(c => Dogs.Any(d => d.Color.Id == c.Id))
```

These will give you all of the colors which are used by the dogs.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Good point, then a possible overridden Equals may well check for equality using the identifier. Updated my post in response

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate will currently (3.2.0.GA) only create IN statements from Linq queries if you have a list of values. It will never create a IN ([subquery]) statement, that's just not implemented.

You may want to vote for it here: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2899

Answer (score 0):

You can make a join :

```
from c in Color 
from d in dog
WHERE d.ColorId == c.Id 
select c
```

But that's still a join, so you could as easily try to get the dog colors with one query:

```
var dogColors = (from d in Dogs
                 select d.ColorId).Distinct().List()
```

And then get the Colors:

```
from c in Color
where dogColors.Contains(c.Id)
select c
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a subselect?

It is fairy simple.

```
from d in db.Dogs 
select d.Color
```